# Enable XSL on CentOS?

Tags: php, libxslt

PHP XSL extension seems to be disabled, because the Magento installation tells me so, but I think I have it installed, since

```
rpm -qa | grep xsl
```

shows:

```
libxslt-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64
libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64
```

Now, how do I enable it?

Comment: you'd need to enable the php module. just having a library on your drive means nothing to php. if xsl support wasn't compiled directly into php, it'd have an external module you need to install/enable that acts as a translation layer between php's guts and the xsl lib's guts.

Comment: This seems like less of a programming question and more of a sysadmin question.

Comment: look for libxsl in your phpinfo. `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`